# How to check & remove space in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA & I found this code online which help me check if my input is an email address, but it doesn't remove extra spaces. I can't figure out how I can modify the code to add in the removal of space.

I tried to to use Trim like this -> 'emailAddr.Value = Trim(emailAddr.Value) , but it gives me error.

Appreciate if anyone is able to help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 For Each emailAddr In Range("D2:D100").Cells

     If emailAddr.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & emailAddr.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        emailAddr.Font.Color = RGB(225, 0, 0)
    Else
        emailAddr.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        emailAddr.Value = Trim(emailAddr.Value)
   End If
 Next emailAddr
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use a replace?  Emailaddr.value = replace(emailaddr.value,” “,””)

Comment: What happens when you use `WorksheetFunction.Clean()` instead of `Trim()`

Comment: @wallyeye I try replace & it work but I always get the "Run-time error '28': Out of stack space" error.

Comment: You might turn off events before you start the loop with application.enableevents = false.  Then back to true after.  Also, you are checking the entire range whether any of the addresses are changed.  It might be better to do For each emailaddr in union(range(“d2:d100”),target).cells

Comment: @walleye Yes, it works now after added `Application.EnableEvents = False` Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that works for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    For Each emailAddr In Range("D2:D3").Cells

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    emailAddr.Value = Replace(emailAddr.Value, " ", "")
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If emailAddr.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & emailAddr.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        emailAddr.Font.Color = RGB(225, 0, 0)
    Else
        emailAddr.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End If

  Next emailAddr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways and one can combine both ways to get the desired trimmed strings:

1. Replace all spaces. As an email address cannot have spaces anywhere (either at end or in between).
2. A custom UDF using regular expression to remove all kinds of whitespaces.

---

```
emailAddr.Value = Replace(RemoveWhiteSpace(emailAddr.Value)," ",vbNullString)
emailAddr.Value = Replace(emailAddr.Value,Chr(9),vbNullString)
```

---

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(target As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```